# How to open multiple files except some files?

Tags: multiple-files, invocation

Suppose we have several files `f11.txt` `f21.txt` `f31.txt` `f01.txt` `f02.txt` `f03.txt`

Is there any Vim option such that I can open all files except for `f0*.txt`?

Something like `gvim -O * --exclude=*0*`? (-O split files vertically, the first `*` matches all files, the `exclude` is supposed to exclude the `f0*.txt` files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim does not provide such an option, but if you are using bash, and have the `extglob` option set (`shopt -s extglob`), you can use the `!(pattern-list)` sub-pattern to match all files except those matching one of the given patterns. (See `man bash` and search for `!(`.).

With that, you can open your files using

```
gvim -O !(*0*)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, two questions. Do you mean that the line `shopt -s extglob` should be added into the `.bashrc` file? If I'm using windows cmd line, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, `shopt -s extglob` should be added to your `~/.bashrc` because it is off by default, at least in bash 4.2.45. I don't know of anything similar in the Windows Command Prompt, but I don't know Windows very well. I use Cygwin to keep my sanity while using Windows.